# Use css to not show the text box

Tags: css, input, textbox

I have text box and what happens is that the user will click on a button and a string will be generated and displayed in the text box. I need to use a text box as that I can use the "name" attribute for posting, but I do not really need the box, so what I really want to know is how in css can I not display the box? I won't be able to use hidden because then user won't be able to see the text.

Thank you

Comment: Huh? So you want to hide the border and background of the box so *only* the text is visible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide the text box border/container but still display the contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the border and make the background color of the textbox transparent (or to whatever color your page is).

```
#textBox
{
   border: none;
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="example" style="border: none;">
```

and if you want to use simple span instead of input box:

```
<span id="example"> </span>
```

and JS code to change its contents:

```
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = 'test';
```